# Prevent converting string containing an E and numbers to number

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute, jquery-data

We have this 'strange' situation where some product codes, for example 11E6, which are stored in data attributes (ex data-prodcode) are getting converted to 11000000, when retrieved inside jquery click function. Something like this:

```
    <a data-prodcode="11E6">click</a>
    var code = $(this).data('prodcode');
    console.log(code); --> 11000000
```

Any advice on how to avoid this behavior or what may cause it?

Comment: That's because `.data` attempts to auto-convert values into numbers or Booleans when possible, and the string `11E6` looks like [a number in scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation) to a computer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/) :

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value
>   (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null) otherwise
>   it is left as a string. To retrieve the value's attribute as a string
>   without any attempt to convert it, use the attr() method.

You may use `attr` in order to avoid automatic parsing :

```
var code = $(this).attr('data-prodcode');
```

To be more precise : this shouldn't happen. And in fact it doesn't happen in last versions. Here's the code of current's jQuery (the most interesting part is the comment) :

```
    if ( typeof data === "string" ) {
        try {
            data = data === "true" ? true :
                data === "false" ? false :
                data === "null" ? null :
                // Only convert to a number if it doesn't change the string
                +data + "" === data ? +data :
                rbrace.test( data ) ? jQuery.parseJSON( data ) :
                    data;
        } catch( e ) {}
```

And it works in jQuery 1.8 and 1.9 : it doesn't convert the string to a number if a back conversion doesn't produce the same string. But it didn't work in jQuery 1.7.

Comment: Be sure to add a comment in your code explaining why you're doing this, so some well-meaning optimizer doesn't change it back later on.

Comment: In fact, jQuery's `data` function is very dangerous for strings in my opinion. It really looks like they were trying to be too smart here...

Comment: Well, this is probably an edge case. Anyone who NEEDS strings in all cases can and should use your solution, which is probably more efficient than `.data` anyway.

Comment: @Blazemonger I studied jQuery's code. In fact it was a bug, now fixed (or probably fixed, it's not a so simple code...).

Comment: Not too smart on our side, the not reading the documentation :) Thanks for ultra fast response/help @ dystroy @Blazemonger