# Issue with variable and if statement in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Why code fragments that looks similar works in different ways?

```
<input data-value-max="10">
```

**1.** If script gets `option` from `attr`, it always updates `input` with `option` value:

```
$('input').keyup(function(e) {

  var $this = $(this);
      option = $this.attr('data-value-max');
      val = $this.val();

  if (val > option){   // ←---
    e.preventDefault();
    $this.val(option);
  }

});
```

I mean that if I type `3` or `10`, script updates input to `10`.

**2.** The second variant works just as I expect—it replaces input value only if it is greater then a number in `if` statement:

```
$('input').keyup(function(e) {

  var $this = $(this);
      option = $this.attr('data-value-max');
      val = $this.val();

  if (val > 10){   // ←---
    e.preventDefault();
    $this.val(option);
  }

});
```

So I can't understand why the first variant replaces input value all the time?

Comment: Where is `val` defined in second code ?

Comment: @dystroy missed a line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't parse the values and attributes.

You should know that `"3" > "10"` but `3 < "10"` (in the latter case, `"10"` is automatically converted for the comparison).

Use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) :

```
var option = parseInt($this.attr('data-value-max'), 10);
```

As your attribute has the `data` prefix, you might also use jQuery [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2)'s auto conversion feature :

```
var option = $this.data('value-max');
```

But personally I try to avoid it (especially given the bugs in 1.7 version) and I prefer to be explicit. And it wouldn't work for any value that you can parse as numbers : only those that give the same exact string if `toString` is called on the number (it would fail for `"03"` or `"+03"` for example).

Comment: or simply `(+val > +option)`

Comment: or simply `option = $this.attr('data-value-max')*1;`

Comment: or simpler `option = +$this.attr('data-value-max')` >_>

Comment: or even simpler `option = +$this.data('value-max')` ^.^

Comment: or even even simpler `option = $this.data('value-max')` like said in the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5).

Comment: @abernier That's what I was mentioning in my answer, but be careful as it wouldn't work for `"01"` for example. It tests `+data+""===data`.

Comment: the autoconversion part on `data()` was new to me, n1;)

Comment: @Christoph [Be wary of it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940778/prevent-converting-string-containing-an-e-and-numbers-to-number). Personally I'd be very prudent with such a difficult to predict function.

Comment: That's the point I was interested in. I would never rely on such a "feature" in a real application - but if you don't know about it, you cannot know why it's malfunctioning... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Cleaner:

```
$('input').keyup(function(e) {

    var max_value = $(this).data('value-max') * 1;

    if( this.value * 1 > max_value )
        this.value = max_value;

});
```

You are comparing strings in your first example and in your second you are comparing a string to an integer (`10`). You want to convert your strings to an integer for your expected comparison. One method is the `*1` I used above.

Finally `e.preventDefault()` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is relying on JavaScript's type-coercion to compare.

What you are literally doing is testing if `"3" > 10` which JS interpreter realizes you're trying to do a numeric comparison and converts it internally to `3 > 10`

This is just fine if you understand what the interpreter will try and coerce....similar examples would be:

```
var x = 0;
if(x) { /* do stuff */ } //0 is a falsy (but not === false) value so the test will always fail

var y = "10";
console.log(y * 10) //outputs 100;
```

Answer (score -1):

I suspect your issue has root in weak typing and type conversion. try this:

```
 if(parseInt(val) > 10) { ...
```

Comment: right guess, but wrong way around... Your example works, because val is coerced, but not the first one where both values are strings.

Comment: My comment actually makes no sense at all because it addresses the second (working) code block and not the non-working first one. the point was parseInt() though.